# Retrieve nested hash values ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a nested Hash like this :

```
{
  :a=>{
       :toto=>{
               :foo=>10,
               :bar=>11,
               :baz=>12
              },
       :titi=>"a"
     },
  :b=>{
       :toto=>{
               :foo=>31,
               :bar=>45,
               :baz=>78
              },
       :titi=>"b"
     }
}
```

My goal is to sum all the `:baz` values. I'm sure there is a beautiful way to do this in ruby. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#inject` is very powerful method that works for both arrays and hashes. You can walk through values of hash and sum the needed key to the total sum.

```
hash.inject(0) { |sum, (_,v)| sum += v[:toto][:baz] } # => 90
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {
  :a=>{
       :toto=>{
               :foo=>10,
               :bar=>11,
               :baz=>12
              },
       :titi=>"a"
     },
  :b=>{
       :toto=>{
               :foo=>31,
               :bar=>45,
               :baz=>78
              },
       :titi=>"b"
     }
}

h.inject(0){|sum,(_,v)| sum +=v.fetch(:toto,{}).fetch(:baz,0)}
```

Comment: @prashantsharma Thanks to you also.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This method finds all `:baz` elements, regardless of their path.

```
h = {
  :a=>{
    :toto=>{
      :foo=>10,
      :bar=>11,
      :baz=>12,
    },
    :titi=>"a"
  },
  :b=>{
    :toto=>{
      :foo=>31,
      :bar=>45,
      :baz=>78,
    },
    :titi=>"b",
  },
}

def sum_baz(hash)
  hash.values.reduce(0) do |memo, elem|
    if elem.is_a?(Hash)
      memo += sum_baz(elem)
      memo += elem[:baz] if elem[:baz]
    end
    memo
  end
end

sum_baz(h) # => 90
```